# Confusion about power dissipation in BJT totem pole driver

Tags: transistors, power-electronics, gate-driving

In every reference for using discrete devices in gate driving buffer circuits I have observed the expected power dissipation is equal to the gate drive voltage swing, multiplied by the total gate charge of the FET and the frequency it is to be driven at. I have attached a photo of a typical circuit and the example calculation.

However, I am confused by one thing. How come it is not twice this value? If you are delivering X amount of charge to the capacitance, which dissipates Y amount of power, surely discharging the capacitor will also drain X amount of charge from the gate capacitance and dissipate the same amount of energy? I would expect that the NPN dissipates V * F * Q during the charge cycle and the PNP dissipates V * F * Q in the discharge cycle…

[image: BJT totem pole circuit]

Best,
Jven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In every reference for using discrete devices in gate driving buffer circuits I have observed the expected power dissipation is equal to the gate drive voltage swing, multiplied by the total gate charge of the FET and the frequency it is to be driven at.

Yes

> If you are delivering X amount of charge to the capacitance, which dissipates Y amount of power, surely discharging the capacitor will also drain X amount of charge from the gate capacitance and dissipate the same amount of energy?

Yes. The same amount of energy is dissipated during the charging of a capacitor as is dissipated during its discharge. [See note about a lie below!]

> However, I am confused by one thing. How come it is not twice this value?

Because the energy stored in a capacitor is not \$QV\$ but half that.

$$Energy = \frac{QV}{2}$$

During the charging process, half the energy is dissipated in the transistor, and half stored in the capacitor. During the discharging, the half of the energy that was stored in the capacitor is dissipated. [Again, see lie below]

> I would expect that the NPN dissipates V * F * Q during the charge cycle and the PNP dissipates V * F * Q in the discharge cycle…

Divide them both by 2, and you would be correct [see lie!].

---

**Now the Lie**

The story about half and half isn't quite true. If the gate capacitance of a MOSFET behaved like an ideal capacitor, the story would be true. But the gate of a MOSFET does not behave like an ideal capacitor. So it may not be the case that during gate charging that exactly half the energy sent into the totem pole is dissipated, and exactly half stored in the gate capacitance. What really happens is that some amount of energy is transmitted to the top of the totem pole. A part of it is stored in the gate capacitance, the remainder is dissipated during the charging process. But whatever amount of energy is stored in the gate capacitance, it will be dissipated when the gate is discharged. Over a complete cycle, the amount of energy dissipated is equal to the amount of energy transmitted into the collector of the top totem pole transistor, which again is equal to the collector voltage times the charge passed through the collector.

Comment: "The lie" is a concern for a given direction, but it averages out, i.e. if you don't care about each transistor's dissipation but the total is still as expected.

Comment: To confirm, if the input power to the circuit was 6W, would I expect that the NPN and PNP would each dissipate around 3W? I have seen some discussion elsewhere about how the process of charging a capacitor through a resistance is 50% efficient (approximately). So I am unsure whether for a 6W power input from my isolated supply I’d expect the BJTs to each dissipate 0.75W instead.